# Setting up Multi-Tenant Exchange Server on AWS/EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, exchange, multi-tenancy

I have recently had a couple of clients ask me about setting up a hosted Microsoft Exchange Server solution for them, that operates on servers based in Australia.

While I was looking into this, I noted that there were already some existing businesses that provided such services, and I found myself wondering if it was possible to do something like this myself and host my clients email on locally based cloud servers.

I had a look at Amazon EC2 and there is some documentation there, but I haven't been able to find out how, or if it is feasible, to set up an EC2 Exchange Server that can host email from multiple domains.

I have only just started looking into this, but would appreciate any advice on how to go about setting up a multi-tenant MS Exchange server on EC2?

Do you know of any links to pages with more info?

Comment: Can you host Exchange on EC2? The answer to that is: Can you host a Windows OS on EC2? If yes, then why wouldn't you be able to host Exchange? I don't see how Multi-tenant Exchange hosting has anything to do with EC2 other than EC2's support of the parent OS for Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Not able to comment on hosting on AWS/EC2 specifically but a general observation - keep in mind that if you're talking about hosting *any* system online then you need to have agreed SLAs for availability, etc. with the users, and therefore just to host Exchange for third parties you might be looking at hosting several domain controllers and more than one exchange server with DAGs and load-balanced CAS config just to provide a basic service with a degree of resilience.